# Calculating route length using lat/lon from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has complete route co-ordinates (lat/lon). The data is of every 0.5 meters. I want to calculate distance between every two points and put the result in distance column of mysql table:

```
Lat            lon             Distance 
12.9994     77.66645    0
12.9874     77.76888    0.5
12.8977     77.88404    1.0
12.7899     11.87999    1.5
```

I have written a function in php to calculate like `GetDist($lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2)`, but the issue is every time  `$lat1`,`$lon1`,`$lat2`,`$lon2` has to be fetched from mysql  and after coming out of the function `$lat1` should be updated with `$lat2` and `$lon1` should be updated with `$lon2` and `$lat2`/`$lon2` should acquire new data from Mysql.

Can anyone help me on how to I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this is something that should be done after the data is fetched?

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the distance of your dataset given one point, you can look at [Fastest Way to Find Distance Between Two Lat/Long Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-distance-lookup-given-latitude-longitude).

Then you can calculate the distance "between every two points" in a loop, taking each row's `lat` and `lng` parameter as query.