# Efficiency store coordinates: which database choose and how

Tags: mysql, mongodb, kdtree, haversine

I'm aware this kind of questions is frequently asked. But due to the age of the most ones and the enhancements on databases that I rode, I think it could be a good idea to create a new one.

I try to efficiency store coordinates (100K) in a database and do some operations on it. In others words, I try to store coordinates and get a rapid access to them. A typical operation should return all the records within a circle with a radius of 20km and center with given coordinates.

I rode **MongoDB** has a 2D spatial index that can store lat and long like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6026634/6271092

I also rode that it's possible to store and get coordinates within the circle by using **MySQL**, a **kd-tree** and the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

So my question is, in January 2018, which database and how should I use to store, access and do some operations with coordinates efficiency? Thx.