# XML search or DB search / javascript (client side) or php (server side) calculation

Tags: php, javascript, xml, performance, xml-parsing

Let's say your site has 200,000 unique users a day. So, your server is heavily loaded/pounded; and you do NOT have resources to buy a bigger/better server. So, you are stuck with what you have.

Now, whenever a user comes to your site, you need to do some calculation (calculate distance between user city as detected via GeoIP and some whitelist of cities, figure out the nearest city within 140 mile radius).

Would you do this calculation via PHP or via JavaScript?

**First**, would you precalculate all nearby cities within 140 mile radius of whitelisted cities? For eg: Whitelist city 1 can have 20 nearby cities. Or would you do on-the-fly calculation everytime?

For eg:
Whitelist = Detroit, MI
and nearby city = Kalamazoo, MI (140 miles)

**Second**, if pre-computed: would you store this in **XML** file or some **MySQL** table? Now, we just have to search through a table (mysql or xml no more than 1 mb in size). I am guessing this would be inefficient because client browser (JavaScript) would have to download **1mb** xml and search through it. This would make page load time even slower. Using DB might be faster but then DB load increases (if 200,000 unique users are trying to load the page over the course of a day).

Maybe the best way to do would be to do **precompute**, **store precomputed results in XML**, and then use **PHP** to search through XML and find nearest whitelisted city to user?

Answer (score 0):

If you, the site, are actually relying on the city information, then you must do the calculation on the server.

Database queries are almost always going to be faster than XML searches for sufficiently large XML files. You can optimize the query, MySQL will cache things, etc.

Pre-calculating all city-city distances would be a way to go, for sure. GeoIP doesn't only provide city names, it does give actual latitude/longitude locations as well. I'm sure that the possible list of cities changes rather constantly, too.

I would look into using the geospacial capabilities of MySQL. General over view of searching by coordinates here:

[Fastest Way to Find Distance Between Two Lat/Long Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-distance-lookup-given-latitude-longitude)

In short what you will do is setup a database of the cities you care about, with their lat/long, and query that table based on the GeoIP provided lat/long.

Comment: "In short what you will do is setup a database of the cities you care about, with their lat/long, and query that table based on the GeoIP provided lat/long" --- so, you mean won't really precompute this information? My whitelist of cities won't really change often.

Comment: The list of cities you have, and their location information might not change very often, but who knows what GeoIP will send back as the information on the client location.

Or do you mean you want to normalize all the client locations down to some list as well?

Comment: Well, I mean. I already have a whitelist (about 100 cities). Now, wouldn't it be easier if I also precomputed a second list? For each whitelisted city, I could precompute all possible cities within 140 mile radius. For eg: for Detroit, MI (whitelist city), I could precompute "Lansing, MI". So, if client comes from Lansing, MI. I show Detroit, MI listings. /// Or do you think it's better to simpley store lat/long of whitelist cities. And do on-the-fly calculation everytime (instead of precomputing) a user visits my site?

Comment: But the clients are likely not to come from only your list of known locations. Does GeoIP only ever say the city is one of a _fixed_ list of cities? Can you get that list of cities?

Comment: 1. Yes, client could be from any city. 2. GeoIP provides a list of all cities in their DB http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity  - I could find distance of each of these cities from my whitelist city. And then  save the ones that are within 140 miles from my whitelist city. This way, Foreach Whitelisted-City: I would have a precomputed list all cities within 140 miles of this whitelist city. But I am not sure if this is a good way of doing this.