# Calculate km difference from two coordinates

Tags: php, coordinates, distance

i've to calculate the distance between

```
(40.851774999999996,14.268123999999998)
```

and each coordinates into results of an sql query:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    echo "distance = ". calculateDistance("40.851774999999996","14.268123999999998",$value['lat'],$value['lng'])."<br>"; 
}
```

Where `calculateDistance` is

```
function calculateDistance($targetLat,$targetLng,$currentLat,$currentLng){
    $r    = 6371; // km
    $dLat = $targetLat-$currentLat;
    $dLng = $targetLng-$currentLng; 
    $a    = sin($dLat/2)*sin($dLat/2) + sin($dLng/2)*sin($dLng/2); 
    $c    = 2*atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
    return $r*$c;
}
```

it gives me strange result like:

```
distance = NAN //-> NAN???
distance = 3392.8405117312 // TOO MUCH!
distance = 3392.8405117312 // TOO MUCH!
...
```

Where is the problem? can someone help me to fix it? :)

Comment: Can you provide the minimal example? Too much distracting code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this answer:

[Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)

1. You don't convert from degrees to radians.
2. You formula is incorrect:

They say:

```
 var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
```

You wrote:

```
$a = sin($dLat/2)*sin($dLat/2) + sin($dLng/2)*sin($dLng/2);
```

The cosine is missing in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert degrees to radians before using it in `sin` function.

```
$radians = $degrees * (M_PI/180);
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672759/how-to-calculate-distance-from-lat-long-in-php#9046008) function, too. It looks a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the Haversine formula:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

There are plenty of examples and code snippets in these pages:

- http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula
- http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_distance_between_two_points_on_a_globe

I've used this snippet in my code, which works very well:

http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_distance_between_two_points_on_a_globe#PHP