# Calculate if listing is 'in range' from database values

Tags: php, database, distance, postal-code

Firstly I apologize for the Title! I couldn't think how to word it!

I have a database with all the area codes in the UK with  their average latitudes and longitudes. Now I want to be able to calculate which area codes are within 'n' miles from another.

I tried running a massive calculation on my local host to work out  all the distances and store them in a massive database, so all i have to do is look up the distances later, but it ran out of memory, and I'm wondering if that's the best way to go about it? Am I overlooking an easy way to calculate it on the fly?

So to make it clear, I want people to be able to enter an area code and a range in miles, and then get all the area codes within that range.
The information i have available is a database with the fields:

| Postcode_ID | Pcode | GRID_N | GRID_E | Latitude | Longitude |

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/407989/2493918

Comment: @MarkusHofmann I can work out the distances, but working out which area codes are in range takes a very long time to calculate that way!

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599200/calculate-distance-given-2-points-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: Have you read about the [Haversine Formula](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/haversine-formula-t339/) yet?

Comment: @MarkusHofmann Yes that is the formula that I am using, ooh I've just realized that it can be rearranged to make it a lot nicer for the database I have! Okay I'll get my pad and pen and crunch some maths, see where it leads. I have a feeling I should be able to reduce it something like `if( ((lat1 - lat2) - (long1-long2)) < val ){ include in results }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods to achieve what you want.

1. Check out the "[Haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) [Formula](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/haversine-formula-t339/)" for distance calculation
2. Have a look at [Google Maps API](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20maps%20api%20examples%20area%20codes) [examples](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcode_map.html) on google as these may provide insight on how to solve the problem
3. To store the I recommend using a [PostgreSQL Database](http://www.postgresql.org/) togehter with [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/)

**About PostGIS** *(quote from the site)*:

> PostGIS is a spatial database extender for PostgreSQL object-relational database. It adds support for geographic objects **allowing location queries** to be run in SQL.

If you'll be able to use the above setup, working with the db data will be way easier.

**This might also be useful:**

[PHP Postal (Zip) Code Range and Distance Calculation](https://github.com/rubberneck/php-postal-code)

Have your eyes roll over this and let me know what you think.

Good luck.

Comment: I've also found this: https://www.dougv.com/2009/03/27/getting-all-zip-codes-in-a-given-radius-from-a-known-point-zip-code-via-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Thanks very much, I will explore all these routes, I'm particularly interested by the PostgreSQL Database, I've not heard of anything like that before! I'm currently reading the link you've commented, and I see how they have managed to optimize it is clever!

Comment: I have managed to fix the memory issue on the script I'm running to create a whole database with pre-calculated values. It's going to take over a day to complete if it stays at its current rate! Do you think having this database will be a good idea if it's properly indexed? It should be faster than calculating the distances every time, or am I wrong? (There are going to be just short of 4,000,000 records in the table when it's complete)

Comment: If you're able to save the processed data it'll definitely increase overall performance. Try to pre-process as much as you can. Use cronjobs/tabs to do regular background processing and do as little "on-demand" (per user request) processing as possible. So try to save the processed search results (range in miles, etc.) after a user created a new search. The Database should be able to handle this amount of data, but it depends on the hardware setup in regards to speed and space.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been answered here [How to calculate distance from lat/long in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672759/how-to-calculate-distance-from-lat-long-in-php)

You need to calculate the radius given the distance and determine which additional zip codes are inside of the circle.