# Finding nearby locations within a given radius

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I have stored latitude and longitude for different interesting places in my database.
Whenever a user clicks into any of the interesting places, the show page displays details of the location, along with a google map with a marker pointing at it.

Now I have been trying to implement a button to "Show nearby places", along with a drop-down for ranges (eg. 50km, 100km, 150km), but could not figure out how to do it.

I was wondering how to find the neighboring places within a given range from a selected location, using the latitudes and longitudes I have in my database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-distance-lookup-given-latitude-longitude

Answer (score 3):

You should use [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), it provides builtin methods like:

```
Venue.near([40.71, 100.23], 20)    # venues within 20 miles of a point
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be precise - you need to keep in mind Earth's shape - it is not a plane. So, choose your accuracy level (simple sphere, WGS84) and write some math for it. And what database do you use? Some of them can operate with [spartial inedxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_Index) which may be very useful.

Comment: It supports spartial indexes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

for an easy - not accurate, but fast approach look here on SO [small distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042418/mysql-select-coordinates-within-range/48037966#48037966)

it is using a simple technical logic the fits many problems in real world, but it is fast but not intended do be accurate