# MySQL select coordinates within range

Tags: java, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I've in my database 100 000 addresses (that is records).

Each one of them has its own coordinates (latitude and longitude).

Now, given the geo location of the user (latitude and longitude), I want to show on a map only the addresses inside the 5 miles range (using Google maps v3 APIs).

This means that usually only 5 or 6 addresses have to be shown out of the 100 000 addresses.

One solution could be retrieving all the records and apply a formula in Java to calculate the distance of each address and show it only if it's inside the range.

That would be a waste of processing power, because I would need to retrieve all the records, when I only need to show 5 or 6 of them on the map.

How can I solve this problem on the database side (MySQL), in order to return only the addresses in the 5 miles range?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haversine calculation: Show users within set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437225/haversine-calculation-show-users-within-set)

Comment: What about accepting an answer some 7 years later?

Answer (score 24):

You can use what is called the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $lng . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM your_table HAVING distance < 5";
```

Where `$lat` and `$lng` are the coordinates of your point, and lat/lng are your table columns. The above will list the locations within a 5 nm range. Replace `3959` by `6371` to change to kilometers.

This link could be useful: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Edit: I didn't see you mentioned Java. This example is in PHP but the query is still what you need.

Answer (score 0):

My approach - and I am using it - is to think like a technician, I am happy with +/- 5%

**This solution is not meant to control rockets, boats or a like, and only for distances below ~100km**  its just a solution like [Fermi problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem)

So lets start for a pragmatic solution:

First: for many problems we can ignore that earth is not flat (distance <~100km) ,

The circumference of the earth is more or less 40000 km (more or less exactly for some reason)

A circle has exactly 360 deg.

So 1 km is: 360/40000 deg => 0.00278 deg

And then just select lat/long within this 0.003 per km, it will be something like where long > 42 - 0.003 and long < 42 + 0.003 - same for lat, where 42 is your lat/long as middpoint. The Database will use the indices.

the problem: you get a square as result not a circle (not real distance)

If you need the circle, script it after getting the results.

I just show the official toilette with in 2 km, so a square is ok, and the accuracy, too. The reason is, that there are streets and houses, so people can't walk directly ...

**Edit:** Technical / mathematical explain:

For very small triangles (one angle << 5 deg) you can ignore the use of trigonometry. So sin(5 deg) ~= 5/180*PI

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS calc_distance$

CREATE FUNCTION calc_distance(
    user_lat FLOAT(9,6),
    user_lng FLOAT(9,6),
    field_lat FLOAT(9,6),
    field_lng FLOAT(9,6)
) RETURNS INTEGER

BEGIN
    DECLARE ulat FLOAT;
    DECLARE ulng FLOAT;
    DECLARE flat FLOAT;
    DECLARE flng FLOAT;

    SET ulat = RADIANS(user_lat);
    SET ulng = RADIANS(user_lng);
    SET flat = RADIANS(field_lat);
    SET flng = RADIANS(field_lng);
    RETURN
        6371393
        * ACOS(
            COS(ulat) * COS(flat) * COS(flng - ulng)
            + SIN(ulat) * SIN(flat)
        );
END$
DELIMITER ;
```

Usage

```
if (($radius = $search->getRadiusMeters())) {
    $query['where'][] = "calc_distance($lat, $lng, addr.lat, addr.lng) < $radius";
}
```

Comment: it will improve exec time

Answer (score -1):

I would think MySQL's geo spatial extensions would solve this for you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere

Otherwise you could index on lattitude then query WHERE lattitude > userLat-5miles and lattitude < userLat+5miles. That would massively reduce the number of possible rows to process in the application layer.