# Google Maps API: Loading markers dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a table in my database with about 1000 places.  Instead of throwing the whole table into a javascript array to display on the map at once, how can I load markers near the current center of the map?  And so that when you zoom out, any markers within the map boundaries would load as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do an AJAX request with the boundaries (top, left, bottom and right coordinates) and match your database with that.

Comment: Do you mean the latitude/longitude boundaries of the map?  Like what lat/long is at the top left, top right, etc. and then see if the lat/long of the place is within the bounds of the map?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a DB with some coordinates, but your question is unclear so: Show the markers within x km/miles from your coordinates.

Possible duplicate of [MySQL select coordinates within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042418/mysql-select-coordinates-within-range)