# Store & retrieve POIs on google maps within certain radius

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api

1. I want to store some POIs (point of interests) on google maps for use only within an android app.
2. And then I want to retrieve all POIs within 'x' km range of a user's current location.

So question is:
Is it possible to store custom data on google maps for app's private use? (please provide link to any examples)

Any other fully managed solutions to store & retrieve geospatial data ?? Otherwise what are the best ways to store this data for speedy development ? Probably using something like an AWS service ?

Comment: Could you give concrete examples of what you want Google Maps to find?  Storing it is not a problem.

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay: I need to store my application data like events shared by a user on a location & then display it to other users near that location within my app. Lets say events within 2 km radius of current location. I am thinking if I can rely completely on maps api without using any external db for my app. Is it possible ?

Comment: @user01 without external db seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to store your data *on google maps* as you mentioned. You will need your own database or an external solution for that. Fusion Tables could be a solution although I would not recommend it. There are [tutorials](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232#map) about it if you are interested in this solution.

Any kind of database allows you to store coordinates, but in most cases you will need to write your own functions to do distance calculations with your data. There is [a good article here](http://ralphbarbagallo.com/2011/04/02/an-overview-of-geospatial-databases/) that reviews the different aspects of a few database systems.

MySQL also has [an extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) that can help you with the generation, storage, and analysis of geographic features.

You can also check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21043061/1238965) that explains how to calculate [great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) using the Haversine formula. Once you have this formula in place, you can easily get POIs within a certain range.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use a kml file to store information. When loading you can load the kml file on the top of the google map.