# Filter Google Maps Markers based on Distance

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, haversine

I am looking at filtering google maps markers based on distance from the users current location. I have this set up to bring in markers from a database and display on a map, but I want to limit the display of these markers to **only** show markers with 3 miles of the users current location.

I receive the markers in JSON form (with lat+long detail) as follows:

```
function showMarkers(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    //$('#mapMarkerPositions').html(this.responseText);

                    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    merchantMarkers = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        merchantMarkers[i] = data[i];
                    }
                    resetMarker();
                    reloadMarkers();


                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "filterMarkers.php?s=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

A sample of the JSON received:

```
0: [,…]
0: "<a style="margin-left: 8px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Courier, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">TestMerchant1</a><br>
↵   <button class="seeMerchantButton" onclick="showMerchant('TestMerchant1');showProfile();" value="TestMerchant1">See merchant</button>"
1: "51.503366"
2: "-0.223477"
3: "info"
4: {text: "£5", fontFamily: "Courier, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"}
fontFamily: "Courier, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
text: "£5"
1: [,…]
0: "<a style="margin-left: 8px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Courier, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">TestMerchant2</a><br>
↵   <button class="seeMerchantButton" onclick="showMerchant('TestMerchant2');showProfile();" value="TestMerchant2">See merchant</button>"
1: "51.503393"
2: "-0.226599"
3: "info"
4: {text: "£3", fontFamily: "Courier, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"}
fontFamily: "Courier, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
text: "£3"
```

I centre the map on the users location as follows:

```
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                });
            }
```

I assume the most efficient way to deal with this is through filtering the JSON, but I don't even know where to start here as I am new to the Google Maps API? I believe applying haversine formula methodology could work there, but again, not sure how this would work?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: *I assume the most efficient way to deal with this is through filtering the JSON* - if you say so... Why did you not share a sample of your JSON? Does it contain the distance already? You must provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue (alternatively to understand what you are trying to deal with). What's the issue with implementing the Haversine formula? etc. etc. etc. Your question, as it is, is too broad, unclear and off-topic.

Comment: Where does the JSN come from?  If it comes from a database (or a service that allows restricting the data be distance from a point), that would be more efficient.   Once you have gotten both sets of data, you can perform the check in the browser before displaying the markers.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks for adding - I've included the sample above which I think is what you are looking for but I am new to this so let me know if that is acceptable?All data is stored in an SQL database, so technically filtering could be done on the lat/long in the database, however then I would need to pass the users location and handle in PHP which for now I think is slightly too complex no?

Comment: If your JSON contains let's say 50 different locations (sets of coords), you would then need to run 50 distance calculations, client-side, either through a calulation method of your own, or through the API which has functions for that. If instead, you pass the user's coordinates to your PHP script, and retrieve the locations list using the Haversine formula, then this is all done in 1 request in your DB. Most probably more efficient, and quicker (and much cleaner). It's not that complex. All you need is to copy the query and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: There are tutorials on how to filter the data by distance in your database.  It will be simpler if it is GIS enabled.  You can pass the users position (and probably the distance to filter by) back to your server in the request for the JSON data.

Comment: Example query here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21043061/1238965

Comment: Instead of the old-school XMLHttpRequest, there are JS frameworks that make it easier and/or you can use the newer [fetch API](https://caniuse.com/fetch).

Comment: @MrUpsidown I've investigated this and you're right, its far easier to pass to the php script. I've managed to get user locations into usable lat/long coords, however how would that be passed as a separate variable to filterMarkers.php above? I'll post a solution once that is figured out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was quite simple and in line with what was suggested in comments.

Pulling the location for the current user was done like this

```
function showPosition(position) {
  y.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + "latlong" + position.coords.longitude;
```

I then pass this to the PHP script and filter using the haversine formula in the script itself as it is far more efficient