# Zipcode Radius Search with POINT Column

Tags: mysql, geolocation, geospatial

I have a MySQL Routine that is getting records within a 50 mile radius when passed Latitude and Longitude via utilizing the Haversin equation.

While this works great, and is pretty speedy (considering it's searching through 82k records), I am thinking that I can get better performance by creating a similar procedure utilizing a POINT column.

So, in my table I created an extra column called `Location`, gave it a datatype of POINT, updated my data to pass lat & lon to the `Location` column.   Data is valid, and is fine., and added a `Spatial Index`

The question is, how can I convert the following query to use the `Location` column, instead of `lat` and `lon` columns.

```
SET @LAT := '37.953';
SET @LON := '-105.688';

SELECT DISTINCT
BPZ.`store_id`,         
3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@LAT - abs(Z.`lat`)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@LAT * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(Z.`lat`) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@LON - Z.`lon`) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2))) as distance,
c.`name`,c.`address`,c.`city`,c.`state`,c.`phone`,c.`zip`,c.`premise_type`
FROM
`zip_codes` as Z, 
`brand_product_zip` as BPZ
LEFT JOIN `customers` c ON c.`store_id` = BPZ.`store_id`
WHERE
BPZ.`zip` = Z.`zip`
AND 
3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@LAT - abs(Z.`lat`)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@LAT * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(Z.`lat`) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@LON - Z.`lon`) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2))) <= 50
ORDER BY
distance LIMIT 20
```

I understand that this has been asked before, however, everything I see points to calculations based on `lat` and `lon` and not the `POINT` column

Updated Code:

```
SET @lat = 41.92;
SET @lon = -72.65;
SET @kmRange = 80.4672; -- = 50 Miles

SELECT *, (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@lat - abs(`lat`)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(`lat`) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((lon - `lon`) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2)))) as distance
FROM    `zip_codes`
WHERE   MBRContains(LineString(Point(@lat + @kmRange / 111.1, @lon + @kmRange / (111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat)))), Point(@lat - @kmRange / 111.1, @lon - @kmRange / (111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))))), `Location`)
Order By distance
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: if you can geocode you data into a point, how about just going after say LIMIT 5 or the like on your query when you are going after some close points

Comment: really not sure what you are talking about and how it relates to my question.  I need 20 records back from this, hence the `LIMIT 20`

Comment: oh i wasnt even looking at your limit, sorry. so you have point data in your db. you create and index on it, and that is the focus of your where clause in the select (not lat and longitude)

Comment: that is what I would like.  Right now, both the `where` clause and the `distance` column are calculated with haversin based on the passed `@LAT` and `@LON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into hilbert curves solutions? A spatial index doesn't deliver the exact solution? . With a mysql spatial index you can use mbrcontains:

```
CREATE TABLE lastcrawl (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, pnt POINT NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT
INTO    lastcrawl
VALUES  (1, POINT(40, -100));

SET @lat = 40;
SET @lon = -100;

SELECT  *
FROM    lastcrawl
WHERE   MBRContains
                (
                LineString
                        (
                        Point
                                 (
                                 @lat + 10 / 111.1,
                                 @lon + 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat)))
                                 ),
                        Point    (
                                 @lat - 10 / 111.1,
                                 @lon - 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat)))
                                 )
                        ),
                pnt
                );
```

Look here: [MySQL - selecting near a spatial point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377960/mysql-selecting-near-a-spatial-point?rq=1).
Here: http://www.drdobbs.com/database/space-filling-curves-in-geospatial-appli/184410998

Comment: Am I able to use that as a `distance` column as well?   Also, what is the 111.1 for?  Is that a potential km radius?

Comment: 111km is roughly a degree longitude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points. Basically yes it's getting the distance and sorting it.

Comment: Per that question, it's the 10 in there that's the distance factor.  How can I factor this into a `distance` column?  See the original question, as I am a bit confused how to apply this.

Comment: Yes, I see. It's fetching a bounding box within 10 km square if you want exact distance you need apply the harvesine formula.  It's cheaper to just the limit the bounding box. Why do you need exact solver?  A spatial index is expensive. Look in my link with the hilbert curves. Hilbert curves are even more expensive.

Comment: Btw. Instead of the harvesine formula you can also use a polygone with mysql?

Comment: approx distance is fine in the `Where` clause.  However, I do need an almost exact distance column.   I am finding that this queery is much faster than it was before via utilizing what you posted above, and the haversine formula is proving pretty effective for getting my `distance` column, I was just wondering if I could apply the same principle...  which I see I cannot, since it will only return a boolean response

Comment: Not sure if I understood you. Of course you can get exact solver and fast speed. You need to create a spatial index and use mbrcontains and then the harvesine formula. It's left to you as exercise.

Comment: yes, that is what I have done.  I'll put the new query in an edit to my question.   b.t.w.  query runs in .007~ seconds ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot award the bounty for another 17 hours...  do you think this could get a bigger performance boost by putting the MBRContains into a function?  And the Haversine column?

Comment: Thank you. The problem with r-tree is that they  can overlap and you need maybe 2 queries for a mbr. Other database uses quadtrees or hilbert curves. If you need a faster speed I would try my php class with hilbert curves. It uses a quadkey and a simple string search. Then you can put an index on that quadkey? Maybe it's faster then the r-tree thing? You can download my hilbert curve class at phpclasses.org?

Comment: :)  Thanks for all this.   Class looks pretty interesting... wow it's been awhile since I was on that site :)

Comment: A quadkey is easy enouh. Translate the geo coordinate into a binary and concatenate it and treat the result as a base-4 number. Check the ms bing tiles map system for a source code:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

The article [Nearest-location finder for MySQL](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/) explains in detail various options, and the best choice for use with the [Spatial Extensions starting with MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html).

From the article, this sample query lists zip codes within a 50 mile radius from given coordinates (42.81, -70.81):

```
SELECT zip, primary_city,
       latitude, longitude, distance_in_mi
  FROM (
SELECT zip, primary_city, latitude, longitude,r,
       69.0 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint))
                 * COS(RADIANS(latitude))
                 * COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS(longitude))
                 + SIN(RADIANS(latpoint))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance_in_mi
 FROM zip
 JOIN (
        SELECT  42.81  AS latpoint,  -70.81 AS longpoint, 50.0 AS r
   ) AS p
 WHERE latitude
  BETWEEN latpoint  - (r / 69)
      AND latpoint  + (r / 69)
   AND longitude
  BETWEEN longpoint - (r / (69 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
      AND longpoint + (r / (69 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
  ) d
 WHERE distance_in_mi <= r
 ORDER BY distance_in_mi;
```