# mysql nearst neighbour search

Tags: mysql, location, nearest-neighbor

i'm a bit new to GIS and i want to search for the k-nearest neighbor in my DB (mySQL)
.
from what i understand the options are:
1) use the Haverstine formula - but it will run on the entire DB, i know i can add indexs to the lat and long to improve things..
2) use expanding area as described here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/isaac/archive/2008/10/23/nearest-neighbors.aspx
3) use Bounding Boxes as described here: http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/appengine/articles/geosearch.html
4) using point and MBRContains function as described here:
[Fastest Way to Find Distance Between Two Lat/Long Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-distance-lookup-given-latitude-longitude)

i'm wondering what are the pros and cons of each way, and which one (or combination) is best for obtaining a FAST and mildly accurate results.
in addition, should i use points & polygons or just lat/long?
i know this topic has been discussed here more then once but i'm still not sure what the answer is.
TNX

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use this soultion by Alexander Rubin, a Senior Consultant at MySQL (2006)
it uses lat and long.
it can be found here:
http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331768736541&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fassets.en.oreilly.com%2F1%2Fevent%2F2%2FGeo%2520Distance%2520Search%2520with%2520MySQL%2520Presentation.ppt&ei=nC1hT4KlD6mk0QX1uOmGBw&usg=AFQjCNF-JRRwbrOhQPim3d1wRDc2dI8HsQ&sig2=uoRdf1PMkZTNSh7m7zXu-A

hope it will help some of you