# Selecting nearest geo coordinates using spatial index on mysql table not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql MyISAM table with many rows that contain information about places, such as geo coordinates and placenames.

I want to select the nearest place from this table depending given an input latitude and longitude. I want to do this creating a column with points of the geocoordinates, using a spatial index and MBRContains to select the data.

I get an error when selecting the data. I will write down the steps that I did here:

## Step 1

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mypoint Point;

UPDATE  mytable
SET     mypoint = Point(lat, lon);

ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mypoint NOT NULL;

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sx_mytable_coords ON mytable(mypoint );
```

Result: 
I see this in the mypoint column (I'm not sure if that's oke, but it's the same for all records): `[GEOMETRY - 25Bytes]`
I see that the index was added: `Name: mypoint  Type: SPATIAL   Field: mypoint (32) Collation: A`

## Step 2

I tried to select the data in two ways:

1. This is recommended for version lower than MySQL 5.1 (My case)

   ```
   SET @lat = 40;
   SET @lon = -10;


   SELECT  *
   FROM    mytable
   WHERE   MBRContains(LineFromText(CONCAT(
           '('
           , @lon + 10 / ( 111.1 / cos(RADIANS(@lon)))
           , ' '
           , @lat + 10 / 111.1
           , ','
           , @lon - 10 / ( 111.1 / cos(RADIANS(@lat)))
           , ' '
           , @lat - 10 / 111.1 
           , ')' )
           ,mypoint)
   ```

   #### I get this error:

   > 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
   >   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
   >   near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 15
2. This is recommended for version higher than MySQL 5.1

   ```
   SET @lat = 40;
   SET @lon = -10;

   SELECT  *
       FROM    mytable
       WHERE   MBRContains
                       (
                       LineString
                               (
                               Point
                                       (
                                       @lon + 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))),
                                       @lat + 10 / 111.1
                                       ) 
                               Point
                                       (
                                       @lon - 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))),
                                       @lat - 10 / 111.1
                                       ) 
                               ),
                       mypoint
                       )
   ```

   #### I get this error:

   > 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
   >   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
   >   near 'Point ( ' at line 12

Comment: See the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) on information about how to format a post with Markdown.

Comment: Also, wouldn't you be better of in performing these calculations on PHP side, rather than the query itself?

Comment: @Truth I'm doing the calculations on PHP side right now, but it's pretty slow. I found that this should be the fastest way for a Mysql table.

Comment: Pretty slow? How fast do you need it I can't imagine even having 0.5 seconds of calculations is THAT bad. Or maybe your calculation algorithm needs rethinking. Please add the PHP code you're currently using.

Comment: @Truth See an earlier post of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432222/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-select-nearest-geographical-place-from-mysql-database

Comment: I actually need it really fast since this calculation has to be performed many times for a single request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing bracket, you're not closing your LineFromText.

Try:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MBRContains(LineFromText(CONCAT(
    '('
    , @lon + 10 / ( 111.1 / cos(RADIANS(@lon)))
    , ' '
    , @lat + 10 / 111.1
    , ','
    , @lon - 10 / ( 111.1 / cos(RADIANS(@lat)))
    , ' '
    , @lat - 10 / 111.1 
    , ')' ))
    ,mypoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're missing a `)`.
2. You're missing a `,` between the two `Point` function calls.

Answer (score 0):

isn't needed `,` separator between point in LineString?
Something like

```
LineString(1 1,2 2,3 3)
```

OR

```
LineString
(
   Point
   (
        @lon + 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))),
        @lat + 10 / 111.1
   ) 
   ,
   Point
   (
        @lon - 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))),
        @lat - 10 / 111.1
   ) 
)
```