# Return Nearest Place available to Users location using Latitude-Longitude?

Tags: java, mysql, location, latitude-longitude

I want to implement **Nearest Place available to User** algorithm in Java or MySQL.

I have **Stations** table in **MySQL** database which has around 100K records of **Stations with Latitude and Longitude**. If User gives his latitude and longitude as x and y, then I want to return **nearest stations** available from **User's location.**

So please suggest me any algorithm available in **Java or MySQL**.

I tried with the following query, but it seems **slower in performance** -

```
SELECT *,3956*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((user_lat-abs(st.station_lat))*pi()/180/2 ), 2) + COS(user_lat*pi()/180)*COS(abs(st.station_lat) *pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((user_lon-
st.station_lon)*pi()/180/2 ),2))) AS distance FROM Stations st HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-distance-lookup-given-latitude-longitude

Comment: Maybe you should put the algorithm in the question so that people can try to modify it for a better performance- P.S The Algorithm not the implementation

Comment: Thanks @Udo Klimaschewski, it was helpful.

Comment: I suggest using the 'equirectangular projection' rather than the 'law of cosines' for distance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) in the following PHP PDO query. It pulls data from a table with 2.7K records and displays them on a [MAP](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php) in less than 1 second with geocoding.. It defaults cleanly if searching outside range of database(Paris 25 miles).

Use 6357 in formula if kilometers are required instead of miles.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM gbstn HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20");
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$center_lat);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$center_lng);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$center_lat);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$radius);
```