# MySQL can't check if point is within distance ... MBRContains query mistake or Bug?

Tags: mysql, geospatial, distance

I have the following latitude and longitude:

```
lat - 18.9802767 
lng - 72.8142511
```

I am trying the following query for places withint 10 kms from the point of interest.

```
select mbrcontains( geomfromtext(
'LINESTRING(72.8993663648088 19.0702857,72.72913583519122 18.8902677)'
), 
geomfromtext(
'point(18.9802767 72.8142511)'
)  );
```

The Linestring geometry object is derived from the exact point that I am trying to determine is within using the method for mysql 5.1 and above from  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points?lq=1)  example using the formula :

`linestring(point(@lng+10/(111.1/cos(radians(@lat))),@lat+10/111.1), point(@lng-10/(111.1/cos(radians(@lat))),@lat-10/111.1))`

From what I understand the point falls within the Minimum Bounding Rectangle (MBR). However the query returns a `0` for the answer. The above is following the principles given in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points?lq=1)  example.

What is wrong with the query? How can I know if the point is within a certain geospatial distance (in this case the MBR points are calculated using 10 kms from the point given by co-ordinates: `lat - 18.9802767, lng - 72.8142511`).

BTW, I am using MySQL 5.5.32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your point does not fall within the MBR of the line.  Looks like you've reversed the latitude or longitude coordinates on either the line or the point.  Switch the X and Y in `'point(18.9802767 72.8142511)'` to get this point, which will be within the MBR of the line:

`POINT (72.8142511 18.9802767)`

If you are tied to MySQL, you may consider updating to MySQL 5.6, then using the Buffer function to create a circular area from your point of interest, and then use ST_Within to find anything within that circular area.

If you are not tied to MySQL, consider PostGIS, which provides a nice ST_DWithin function that makes these comparisons very easy.

Comment: This is the formula I have used as given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points?lq=1): `linestring(point(@lng+10/(111.1/cos(radians(@lat))),@lat+10/111.1), point(@lng-10/(111.1/cos(radians(@lat))),@lat-10/111.1))` 
So the `Linestring` geometry object is derived from the exact point that I am trying to determine is within. Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Your linestring is probably correct, but the point you are passing to geomfromtext has the x and y flipped, which puts it far away from the linestring.   I've updated my answer to make that more clear

Comment: Thanks I think its working for now. Although having a problem with the table still :-(. Anyways could you explain the logic behind the division by cos ?

Comment: This accounts for the lines of longitude converging at the poles.  As you move north or south from the equator, the number of KM/degree of latitude changes as a function of cos(latitude), from about 111KM at the equator where 111KM*cos(0) = 111KM*1 = 111KM, to 0KM at the poles (because the lines have converged to a point), where 111KM*cos(90 deg) = 111KM*0 = 0KM.  You don't have to do this for longitude, because lines of latitude don't converge, so KM/degrees of longitude is always about 111.

Comment: Thanks a tonne @Ireeder ... that was really helpful.. you rock !!