# RelationShip between lat lng and distance

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

Let say I have lat/lng of a user X e.g 50.597186, 5.449219 and I have a database which contains users(around 1 million) lat and lng  . Now I want to find out the users which is nearby user X for example find all users which is in range of 5 km from the X location. 
How can I find users in database. Any suggestion? I tried [this](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml) website to get relation ship between lat/lng and distance but I do not understand it how?

Comment: you can sort your data in ascending order and after that U can Query the DB to Show with the radius of 5 km from X location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with PHP, use the [haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). It's some tricky trigonometry but works like a charm. Note that negative lon/lat indicates west/south (this convention is not followed universally, check your data to be sure).

If you want to do it all in mysql, you could use haversine, and there is also a syntax to approximate other points in a radius. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points?rq=1).