# How to query all locations that are near a user's position(latitude, longitude) in mysql

Tags: mysql, geolocation

I have table User that contains amoung others collumns, latitude and longitude (Double).
I have another table called Locations that has the same structure (latitude and longitude) (Also double type).

How can I query all the locations that are arround the user on a surface of 10 km in circle?(or a circle with diameter of 10 km).

I've seen that mysql has some Point data type but I never used it so it's very hard to understand.

For example, random coordinates: 
User (latitude=23.102131, longitude=-21.1231241)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks rather like a popular question on Stack Overflow. For example, you can consult answers to this question: [Fastest Way to Find Distance Between Two Lat/Long Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points) and also answers to questions linked to that question.

Here is basic MySQL query solving your concrete problem using Haversine formula:

```
SELECT loc.id
FROM `User` u, Locations loc
WHERE u.id = @user_id
  AND (6371 * acos(cos(radians(u.latitude)) * cos(radians(loc.latitude )) * cos(radians(loc.longitude ) - radians(u.longitude)) + sin(radians(u.latitude)) * sin(radians(loc.latitude )))) <= @circle_diameter / 2;
```

It doesn't use any optimizations, so it may be slow on a large data.

Comment: I've seen a couple of questions that are asking for similar answears, but I am looking for something with an exact answear. For example, if I have in table user a latitude and a longitude how do I manage to get all locations that are near? exactly like this

Comment: OK, I have made my answer more specific.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has spatial query capabilities. I suggest you [read about them.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html)

Comment: Isn't there a way to make it simpler?

Comment: Not a good way, no. It's not that difficult to use the GIS functions, and once you learn them you will be able to accomplish a lot more. Worth learning...