# Given a user's location, select rows that include that user in their radius

Tags: php, mysql, location, coordinates

I have a MySQL table with rows `latitude`, `longitude` and `radius`. Latitude and longitude are of type `DOUBLE`; `radius` is of type `INT` and measured in meters. Essentially, each row represents a circle on Earth.

Given values of `user_latitude` and `user_longitude`, how can I select all the rows that include the user in their circles?

I made a quick diagram to illustrate in case my question wasn't clear. Each red dot represents a `user_latitude` and `user_longitude` point, each circle represents a `latitude`, `longitude` and `radius` row in the database.

[image: diagram]

Comment: What is your current query?

Comment: can use something like
where ( lat_x - $x ) + ( lat_y - $y ) < $r
and    ( lat_x - $x ) + ( lat_y - $y ) > -$r.
[ this is a crude approximation of a circle.. ]

Comment: you dont need to worry about the circles, you just need to care if the distance between the points is less than the radius

Comment: @pala_ that is the definition of a circle

Comment: yes, but you dont need to think about generating the circle.

Comment: Find distance between two points using latitude and longitude in mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370975/find-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-and-longitude-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step1: implement haversine distance formula

```
delimiter //
create function DistanceInKm(
        lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT,
        lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT
     ) returns float
    NO SQL DETERMINISTIC
begin
    return degrees(acos(
              cos(radians(lat1)) *
              cos(radians(lat2)) *
              cos(radians(lon2) - radians(lon1)) +
              sin(radians(lat1)) * sin(radians(lat2))
            )) * 111.045;
END//
delimiter ;
```

(the magic number 111.045 converts it to km, use 69 for miles)

step 2: use the function

`select * from areas where distance(lat, long, USERLAT, USERLONG) < radius`

[reference](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @pala_, one question though. What would the "magic number" be for a radius measured in meters?

Comment: i'm guessing 111045, since a kilometer is a thousand meters

Comment: thanks for the answer, it seems to work based on my testing so far :)