# php slow response time using google maps API

Tags: php

I have a MySQL table in the following format with roughly 500 rows

```
ID¦name¦stuff¦location
```

My php script gets a users location, selects all of the rows from the database and then gets the distance from each rows location to the users location using the google maps API and puts it all in a json array

The problem is even processing 500 rows takes 300 seconds on average, I wanted to get it down to roughly 3-4 seconds somehow, It appears to be the google maps API that's bottlenecking the whole script.

What I'm asking is if there's a better way to handle the whole thing so that I can get the script to process everything in under 10 seconds.

the php script -

```
<?php
//used for benchmarking
$time_start = microtime(true); 
require_once 'db.php';

//get the users location
$location = $_GET['location'];

                //check the users location is valid
           if (checkLocation($location) == "found") {

                  echo "null";

            } else {
                //select all of the rows
                $SQLSelect = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `something`");
                    $array = array();
                    $count = 0;
                    while ($show = $SQLSelect -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        $distance = getDistance($location, $show['location']);
                            $distance = $distance * 0.000621371192;

                                        //narrow down the distance
                                        if ($distance < 100) {

$array[$count] = array();
$array[$count]['name'] = $show['locationName'];
$array[$count]['spec'] = $show['spec'];
$array[$count]['distance'] = round($distance);
                                        $count = $count + 1;
                                        }
                    }
                    //sort the array based on distance
usort($array,function($a,$b) {return strnatcasecmp($a['distance'],$b['distance']);});
                    echo json_encode($array);
            }


              function getDistance($start, $end) {
                    $from = $start;
                    $to = $end;
                    $from = urlencode($from);
                    $to = urlencode($to);

                    $data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&language=en-EN&sensor=false");

                    $data = json_decode($data);
                    $time = 0;
                    $distance = 0;
                    foreach($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
                    $time += $road->duration->value;
                    $distance += $road->distance->value;
                    }

                    return $distance;
                    }



                    function checkLocation($start) {
                    $from = $start;
                    $to = 'location1';
                    $from = urlencode($from);
                    $to = urlencode($to);

                    $data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
                    if (strpos($data, '"status" : "NOT_FOUND"') !== false) {
                    return "found";
                        } else {
                            return "null";
                        }
                }

                    echo '</br>Total execution time in seconds: ' . (microtime(true) - $time_start);        
?>
```

Comment: you'll never manage to do 500 queries to the Google maps api in 10s ~ you might be better using php to calculate the distances based on a port of the havershine (?) formula

Comment: I tried using something similar but found it to be quite inaccurate

Answer (score 0):

Your only option to speed things up is to do away with all those Google Maps API requests. I would change your script and database table to use latitude and longitude points for the user's location and items in your database.

It is possible to calculate the distance (as a crow flies) between two lat and lng points using MySQL as seen here: [Find distance between two points using latitude and longitude in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370975/find-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-and-longitude-in-mysql)

If you switch to this method you would definitely be able to get your script to run in < 4 seconds.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, I tried using this method but because I also have to calculate long distances it can be inaccurate to a degree of almost 80 miles when calculating a 200 mile trip

Comment: If you're finding inaccuracies that great then you must have had the math wrong. Also keep in mind the the method I mentioned calculates distance in a straight line whereas Google Maps is giving the driving distance along a road.

Comment: Thanks, managed to use longitude/latitude to calculate a guestimated distance and then calculate the extra "road mileage" by adding roughly 1/5 of the journey :)