# MySQL summation of data depending on distance tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, user and places, with `latitude` and `longitude`. For each place, I want to sum users who are within x distance from it.

One possible way of doing this is by looping. Is there any other way to do it? How can I achieve this in plain `SQL`?

Edit:

```
User(id, name, latitude, longitude)

Place(id, name, latitude, longitude)
```

Comment: You should provide your table structure so we understand how they relate, but no, you shouldn't need a loop.  `join` and `count` are what you're looking for.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: Do some research on the MySQL GIS extensions.

Comment: @sgeddes tables' structure is very simple. I have edited the post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370975/find-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-and-longitude-in-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one approach would be a cross join of "user" and "place" (with each "user" matched to each place. Incorporate an expression that calculates the distance between the "user" lat/long and the "place" lat/long (GCD), and compare the result from the expression to the given distance "x", and based on that comparison return a 0 or 1. And use a SUM aggregate of the return from the comparison.

For example, something like this:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.name
     , IFNULL( SUM( [gcd_expr] <= x ) ,0) AS cnt
  FROM place p
 CROSS
  JOIN user u
 GROUP BY p.id
```

With every user matched to every place, that could be really big set. And that's a lot of distances to be calculated, which could be prohibitively expensive.

For improved performance, we could include join predicates that restrict the deltas of latitude and/or longitude ...  say you only want to check users that are within 5 degrees of latitude ...

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.name
     , IFNULL( SUM( [gcd_expr] <= x ) ,0) AS cnt
  FROM place p
  LEFT
  JOIN user u
    ON u.lat-p.lat BETWEEN -5.00 AND 5.00
 GROUP BY p.id
```

The `[gcd_expr]` represents the expression that performs the Great Circle Distance calculation. (There's implementations of that available; search for existing questions on StackOverflow, I know that question has been answered several times.)