# Calculated Columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has two fields (latitude and longitude).
I also have a script that gets the users current latitude and longitude.

I want to get all the rows from the table that are <= 50Km from the users location.
Calculating the distance is not a problem.
My question is how do I restrict unwanted rows in my search result using mysql?

```
$currentLatitude = 10.999;
$currentLongitude = 23.354;
```

MYSQL

```
$this->db->select('latitude, longitude');
$this->db->from('table');
//This is where I have a problem
$this->db->where('distance <=',  50km);

$result = $this->db->get()
```

Comment: Provide the sample data and your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find distance between two points using latitude and longitude in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370975/find-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-and-longitude-in-mysql)

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks. Wasn't it exactly but I've been able to modify it to what I need and it's working. Thanks again.