# How to get distance (latitude and longitude) from mysql query [PHP,MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table in mysql database.
[image: table]

This is my PHP file:

```
$user_latitude = 45.11123;
$user_longitude = 20.33445;

$query = "";
```

I want to create a query that returns the ids (of the rows in the table) in order of distance from user position($user_latitude,$user_longitude).
I want to do this by using a MySQL query.

Comment: where is the rest of the query? or did you want some pointers or write it for you?

Comment: I don't write the rest because it's not important I'm interesting only in the query.

Comment: Well then, I guess it's not important that I keep asking more questions. Some of which stand to be asked by others. Good luck with this.

Comment: [Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/574736/7799650

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula below to calculate the distance. For more info look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370975/find-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-and-longitude-in-mysql)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, (6371 * acos (cos (radians($user_latitude))* cos(radians(latitude))* cos( radians($user_longitude) - radians(longitude) )+ sin (radians($user_latitude) )* sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance FROM table_name WHERE 1 ORDER BY distance DESC");
```

The provided distance will be in Kilometers. If you need Miles, use 3959 instead of 6371.

Comment: Thank you and how can I set a limit, like 10 km?

Comment: You can use `WHERE distance < 10`