# Calculating distance with latitude longitude pair in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlgeography

I have the following table in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/383af/4)

```
a   b   alat    alon    blat    blon
A   X   40      -76      26     -80
B   Y   41      -74      24     -81
C   Z   42      -73      24     -80
```

I would like to use a select query to add a numeric distance column.

My current try is

```
select a,b,alat,alon,blat,blon,
GEOGRAPHY::Point(alat, alon,4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(blat, blon, 4326))
from lat_lon
```

but I get the error

> Incorrect syntax near 'GEOGRAPHY'

How can I include a distance column in my select statement?

Comment: sql fiddle is empty

Comment: SQLFiddle loaded ok for me @Simonare

Comment: Depend the SQLFiddle you use MySql. But you tagged sql-server. Which one is correct?

Comment: Sorry, SQLFiddle should be MS SQL SERVER.

Comment: Theres an answer to this already, using cos and sin, i think its applicable to both ms sql and mysql
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/383af/9/0
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370975/find-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-and-longitude-in-mysql

Comment: The query you posted works perfectly on SQL Server.

Comment: Your syntax is correct, take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7643fa6ca8e13bdf505feb995c80a5cf

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you using? You need to have at least 2008 for  GEOGRAPHY and  at least 2012 for STDistance.

Comment: @ZekiGumus I am using SQL 2016.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti and satischcse pointed out that this query for this example seems to work. For whatever reason it fails on my real data. Something I need to solve. I found the alternative by ivan to be most useful for a simple alternative which does not require GEOGRAPHY.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is running fine (please see screenshot below):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I include a distance column in my select statement?

Check your select statement what are you running, it might be missing `.` before STDistance.

[image]

And SQL you posted here working fine..

[image]