# PHP MySQL How to calculate distance for between row?

Tags: mysql, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a table like this:

```
stepID   | UserID| Date        | Lat        | Lng
1        |1      | 2019-10-11  | -7.2905838 | 112.5655568
2        |1      | 2019-10-11  | -7.2349607 | 112.6106177
3        |1      | 2019-10-11  | -7.2345435 | 112.6112432
4        |1      | 2019-10-12  | -7.2529265 | 112.6542999
```

I need to calculate distance that user has been visited on the same day (for example 2019-10-11). So waht will be show on PHP page is (the KM amount below is an example) :

```
From step 1 to 2: 2 KM
From step 2 to 3: 3 KM
From step 3 to 4: 3 KM
TOTAL FOR TODAY: 8 KM
```

I've googling and also search in this stackoverflow's history but didn't found like what I face today. Need your suggestion how to query this.
Thank you before, GBU always.

Comment: sorry for text format, I will change the text layout so everyone will not confuse

Comment: Hi @juergen d,  Thanks for fixing text layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best task for MySQL. It would be much better to perform it in any programming language by reading rows from DB 1 by 1.
However if you want to use exactly MySQL then something like that (assuming StepIDs are sequential numbers without gaps):

```sql
SELECT UserID, SUM(km) total
FROM (
  SELECT t1.UserID, 
    DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(t1.Lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(t2.Lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(t1.Lon- t2.Lon))
         + SIN(RADIANS(t1.Lat))
         * SIN(RADIANS(t2.Lat))))) km
  FROM table t1
  JOIN table t2 ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID and t1.StepID = t2.StepID - 1
) t
GROUP BY UserID
```

I've got the formula from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24372831/2244262

Comment: Hi @Stalinko, thank you for your suggestion. GBU always

Comment: Hi @Stalinko, sorry for late reply. Didn't work because MySQL says "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"...while I've make an alias for each column like this:

Comment: SELECT SUM(km) total FROM (SELECT a.user_id, 
DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(a.activity_result_lat_in))
* COS(RADIANS(b.activity_result_lat_in))
* COS(RADIANS(a.activity_result_lng_in- b.activity_result_lng_in))
+ SIN(RADIANS(a.activity_result_lat_in))
* SIN(RADIANS(b.activity_result_lat_in))))) km 
FROM tbl_activity_result a INNER JOIN tbl_activity_result b
ON a.user_id = b.user_id and a.activity_result_id = b.activity_result_id - 1) WHERE a.user_id = 170 AND date(a.activity_date) >= '2019-10-28' AND date(a.activity_date) <= '2019-10-28' GROUP BY a.user_id

Comment: @rizal, all correct. In your example you don't have an alias for the sub-query. Add something before "where".

Comment: Finally it worked. Thank you for your correction @Stalinko.

Comment: @rizal if my answer helped you please mark it as correct :)

Comment: hi @Stalinko, sorry I just logged in again today. I've marked.it. Thank you for your help.