# Distance units in a query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query, that selects places withing given radius:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    group, 
    name,  
    111.1111 *
    DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(".$lat."))
       * COS(RADIANS(t1.lat))
       * COS(RADIANS(".$lon.") - RADIANS(t1.lon))
       + SIN(RADIANS(".$lat."))
       * SIN(RADIANS(t1.lat))))) AS distance
  FROM t1
) AS grp
WHERE distance < 10
```

It works well, but I'm not sure if returned results are in miles or kilometers. I suspect KM  and if that's the case, how do I convert it to miles?

Comment: Where did you get the formula from? Did the author not give you the units?

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: Is this really a question for Stack Overflow? Finding out if it's miles or kilometers is as simple as running a query for a pair of coordinates and comparing it with the answer you get for those coordinates off Google. If it is indeed in km, converting to miles is also a simple multiplication by a constant. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to originate in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24372831/4386278) by [O. Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205608/o-jones), which also states:

> The constant 111.1111 is the number of **kilometres** per degree of latitude, based on the old Napoleonic definition of the metre as one ten-thousandth of the distance from the equator to the pole.

Accordingly, the original query uses the name `distance_in_km` for the result.

Jones goes on to say:

> If you want statute miles instead of kilometres, use 69.0 instead.

Comment: Oh, cool. It appears I found the query that was borrowed from the OP you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @Asteroids presumably because all you do in this answer is quote and link another answer. This could have been a comment instead of an answer

Comment: @PranavHosangadi No, comments are not for answering questions, ever. This answer answers the question, with the facts inline _and_ references to the source of the information. What more do you want!?