# Better way to compare distance between multiple users

Tags: api, matrix, distance

I've been using the google distance matrix API, and so far it works very well! However, I've noticed that google put a limit of 1000 requests per day. I am making a program for a website with about 1000 users, and the way I plan to search through all the users would lead to a lot of requests every time someone searched for nearby people.

I was planning to save everyone's location in a database, and then when someone entered their own location, it would compare that location to each and every one in the database. This would lead to potentially hundreds/thousands of requests every time someone searched.

So would there be a better way to do this?

Comment: If your database is MySQL you can use the answer to mysql - Fastest Way to Find Distance Between Two Lat/Long Points -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points

Comment: What if I just wanted to save their location, as in (Toronto, Ontario)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a heavy request method you currently doing. And even if you buy the commercial solution I fear you will loose money very quickly.

Instead I suggest that you host a routing server on your own (e.g. GraphHopper where I am the author) and then you can query this until the CPU melts. Also for only a city the hardware requirements are very low.