# Searching for records in database within a certain distance calculated by coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble with this query:

```
SELECT Store_name, GPS_latitude, GPS_longitude, SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (GPS_latitude - $longitude), 2) +
POW(69.1 * ($latitude - GPS_longitude) * COS(GPS_latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM table HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance
```

The user of the website should be able to input coordinates (latitude and longitude). From there on I want the query above to list the stores in the table ordered by how close they are to the user given $latitude and $longitude.

I do get results, but only if i edit the query from 'distance < 25' to 'distance < 5000' (or other large number), although the results does not seem to be in order based on distance from the user given coordinates.

Is it the query which calculates this the wrong way? I am quite stuck and i can't seem to find any solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points

Comment: Separate each part of the query, select it and see how much it is and compare it to how much is should be.. I doubt anyone here will sit now to see that you mathematical logic is correct..

Comment: @MaxU - thank you for your answer. I did not find it helpful, i am afraid.

Comment: @sagi Thank you. I am not that familiar with SQL, would you care to elaborate how I can separate each part of the query?

Comment: what are the meaning of the constants 69.1 and 53.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from (
    SELECT Store_name, GPS_latitude, GPS_longitude,
    SQRT(
        POW(69.1 * (GPS_latitude - $longitude), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * ($latitude - GPS_longitude) * COS(GPS_latitude / 57.3), 2)
    ) AS distance
    FROM table
) as vtab
WHERE distance < 25
ORDER BY distance;
```

PS but i would strongly recommend you to take a look at the "MySQL-Specific Spatial Relation Functions"

Comment: +1 for using Spatial Relation functions. This query will be unbearably slow once your database starts to grow...

Comment: @NevilleK, thanks! I'm not a fun of "reinventing the wheel" approach ;)