# MySQL-Join two table based on nearest city

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables. Table A structure is

```
City | State | Country | Latitude | Longitude | LocPoint(Longitude,Latitude)(spatial index)
```

I have created spatial index on column  **LocPoint**  of datatype Point.

Table B

```
Latitude | Longitude
```

I want to Join two tables A and B with City State and Country information of the nearest city to the location of points in table B. I know the formula of getting the nearest point, I am just stuck at the join part where  i will join only for the nearest point.

Expected OutPut after running the query

`Latitude(TableB) | longitude(TableB)| City(Nearest from lat/Lon from Table A) | State | Country`

Any ideas?

Comment: I should mark it as duplicate again. You didnt add anything new.

Comment: No, It is not about the nearest city part, I get that but I don't know how to apply that on a join condition. I haven't seen a similar example with implementation on join

Comment: You cant make a join right now. You need to calculate the distance to each city, then choose the nearest `City_id` and then you can do the `JOIN`

Comment: That was what i was wondering if we can get the nearest city and join it in a single query.

Comment: No, you can not. I mean you can do it In a single query, but is very big.

Comment: Can you suggest me in that direction, I will try if i can implement that. I need to form the output table in a single query instead of doing it iteratively. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Lets call a [**function**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points) `dst` to calculate the distance between two point to simplify.

Now you need to calculate every distance between your point in TableB with your cities.

```
 SELECT TA.*, TB.*, dst(TA,TB) as distance
 FROM TableA TA
 CROSS JOIN TableB TB
```

Now you need to choose the smallest distance for each TableB entry using variables. Would help if you have a PK for TableB. If you dont have a PK you can use `CONCAT (tableB.Latitud,tableB.Longitud)`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
           @rn := IF(@pk = tb_pk,
                     @rn + 1,
                     IF(@pk := tb_pk, 1, 1)
                    ) as rn       
    FROM (
         SELECT TA.*, TB.*, dst(TA,TB) as distance
         FROM TableA TA
         CROSS JOIN TableB TB
         ) T
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @pk := 0 ) as var
    ORDER BY distance DESC -- Find the near city
   ) Y
WHERE Y.rn = 1  -- Only select the first city for group.
```

Comment: did this help or have more questions?

Comment: I tried to implement that query but it was taking a long time even after indexing both tables. I have 1000 rows in tableB and 100000 rows in table A. I am thinking about having a different approach..

Comment: Of course is slow. that is `100.000.000` calculations. You have to do some optimizations. Like only calculate the distance against the cities in a box around each TableB element. Precalculate the sin / cos values because those are the slower operations. And you dont calculate every TableB, you perform a loop and keep saving the result in a temporary table. Other option is use a different db, I do things like this in postgres, and find the near_link for 4000 records I receive every minute in less than 5s.