# work with position and MYSQL (latitude and longitude)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, position

hi I have a Branches with a Position table

in my Branches Model class I have:

```
public function position()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Model\Branch\Position');
}
```

in the Position table I have:

```
protected $fillable = ['latitude','longitude','branch_id','business_id'];

public function branches()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Model\Branch','branch_id');
}
```

now I get the latitude and longitude of my client

how I can show him what branches he have in here 20 KM radios?

the simple why with Eloquent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points

Comment: To ask an On Topic questions, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Answer (score 0):

Am using below code for similar task.It is working for me:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
      return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
  } else {
      return $miles;
  }
}
```

Please refer to the below link for detail:

http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php