# Calculate distance between two long/lat

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

After researching a lot and not coming to a solution i have to ask. 
How can I calculate the distance between two Long/Lat Points in Mysql? (efficient way?)

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points) solution, but there I dont know which @lat @long is and i am not using Points because spring-data-jpa doesnt allow a Geometry Type (Except using MysqlSpatial dialect)

In Java i am calculating like this:

```
private double getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2) {
    int R = 6371; //Earth Radius
    double dLat = degreeToRadiant(lat2-lat1);
    double dLon = degreeToRadiant(lon2-lon1);
    double a =
            Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                    Math.cos(degreeToRadiant(lat1)) * Math.cos(degreeToRadiant(lat2)) *
                            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
            ;
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    return R * c; //Distance in km
}
```

And my table/Entity contains one column for longitude and another for latitude.

Another question, could there be a possibility to solve this with as said before with spring data jpa?

I tried to translate the Java code to Mysql, but the Distances are to high.

```
SELECT name, (6371 * (
    2 * ATAN2(
                SQRT(
                    SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-latitude))/2) * SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-latitude)/2)) +
                    COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(48.3069400)) * SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-longitude)/2)) *
                    SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-longitude)/2))
                ),SQRT(
                    1-(SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-latitude))/2) * SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-latitude)/2)) +
                    COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(48.3069400)) * SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-longitude)/2)) *
                    SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-longitude)/2)))
                )
            )
)) as distance FROM event
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest Way to Find Distance Between Two Lat/Long Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points)

Comment: I already linked that in the third sentence...

Comment: @MarkusG.what is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7.x the most effective way IMHO is to use geometry function:

```
SELECT st_distance_sphere( POINT( lat1, long1) , POINT(lat2, long2 ));
```

you'll get the distance in meters.

On MariaDB st_distance( ... ) will return similar result.

Comment: Indeed, the [compatibility matrix](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlmariadb-spatial-support-matrix/)  indicates that MariaDB does not support distance functions.

Comment: @MarkusG. use ST_DISTANCE ()

Comment: Thank you, but i have to multiply by 100 to get the kilometers but some points are not right I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the solution and the mistake in my code above, i forgot to insert the longitude haha

For those who are also searching for such a code, the following code calculates the distance between a given point and the coordinates in a table row.
Where the number with `48.306... is the given latitude` and the number with `14.28... is the given longitude`

The distance is calculated in km and the number 6371 is the Earth Radius.

```
SELECT name, (6371 * (
    2 * ATAN2(
                SQRT(
                    SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-latitude))/2) * SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-latitude)/2)) +
                    COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(48.3069400)) * SIN(RADIANS((14.2858300-longitude)/2)) *
                    SIN(RADIANS((14.2858300-longitude)/2))
                ),SQRT(
                    1-(SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-latitude))/2) * SIN(RADIANS((48.3069400-latitude)/2)) +
                    COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(48.3069400)) * SIN(RADIANS((14.2858300-longitude)/2)) *
                    SIN(RADIANS((14.2858300-longitude)/2)))
                )
            )
)) as distance FROM event
```