# Is better to get distance from two sets of coordinates in the server vs in the client?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a database with ~3000 records and each one of them has a field called coordinates with the coordinates in a string, separated by a comma, for example:

```
coordinates: -32.23192381,51.32238190
```

And then I have some other coordinates:

```
coordinates2: -32.21093841,52.99193764
```

So the algorithm should:

1) Split the string into two pieces: `latitude` and `longitude`.
2) Get the distance using a function like this:

```
function getDistance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2){
  radius = 6371
  dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1)
  dLng = deg2rad(lng2-lng1)
  a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2) 
  c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a))
  return radius * c
}

function deg2rad(deg){
  return deg * (PI/180)
}
```

3) Return an array with the records where distance is less than 10km.

---

I'm using PHP for server and JS for client, so what would be faster:

1) Pass the records from the DB as JSON to javascript and then run the algorithm for every record.

or

2) Do that with PHP and only pass the final array with the records less than 10km.

Which will be faster?

Also, is this too slow? I'll never have more than 3000 records, but it seems to me like it would be slow. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

[do the query on mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points)

also for 3000 records it in the db to run is nothing even if you have no index it will still be fast