# what is the formula to found out the latitude and longitude of customer address in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

what is the formula to find out the latitude and longitude of an address in MySQL?
for example customer address is Freibergstrasse 23 12107. how can I find out its latitude and longitude?

Actually I need to know the distance between customer address and its book hotel address. I have hotel latitude and longitude and i need to know customer address longitude and latitude. I am using only MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Comment: There is a MySQL implementation in the last comment just look for it.

Comment: I dont have latitude and longitude column in my table. I have only address and postal code in my table. I need to findout latitude and longitude. Do you have any idea how to findout latitude and longitude?

Comment: You need to have a programming language to connect to a adress to latitude and longitude service. like Google https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro or the one Ndivhuwo used in this answer..it can't be done with only MySQL

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me this link.

Comment: Are you trying to find the straight-line distance from two points or the driving distance? If you simply want to get the straight-line distance you will likely need to create a mysql function or stored procedure based off of the information similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points

Answer (score 0):

Try using an API to get the coordinates from the address you have.
For example if your program is web based you could use [Map Quest API](https://www.mapquestapi.com)
(Forward Geocoding).
Your call will be something like this: http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=YourOwnRegistrationKey&outFormat=json&maxResults=1&location="Freibergstrasse 23 12107"

Comment: Actually i need to know the distance between customer address and its booked hotel address. I have hotel latitude and longitude and i need to know customer address longitude and latitude. I am not making a web program just using mysql.