# Add range with coordinates in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I want to enter a range of 100 meters radius. The following query works, but I want to add a radius to the point.

```
select *
from rivers
where contains(shape, point(11.698366, 42.235607))
```

I have the points of a river and I want that although I am beside the river I find that I'm on the river

Is this possible, and if so, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: i believe you can use the Haversine formula so you can find rivers within a radius of 100 meters from your longitude and latitude..

Comment: are you asking how calculate distance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points

Comment: check @JuanCarlosOropeza 's link that is indeed the Haversine formula

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a buffer to your point, and check if the two geometries intersect:

```
select *
from rivers
where MBRIntersects(shape, st_buffer(point(11.698366, 42.235607), 100))
```

Comment: #1305 - FUNCTION table.st_buffer does not exist

Comment: I have seen that it needs at least version 5.6 of MySQLto use st_buffer. I have 5.5 of My sql, I need to update. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlmariadb-spatial-support-matrix/