# MySQL: Distance Between Two Points (using MBRContains)

Tags: mysql, sql, location

In the post [Fastest Way to Find Distance Between Two Lat/Long Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points), user Quassnoi provides the following code for calculating the distance between two locations:

```
    SELECT  *
    FROM    table
    WHERE   MBRContains
                    (
                    LineString
                            (
                            Point (
                                    @lon + 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))),
                                    @lat + 10 / 111.1
                                  ),
                            Point (
                                    @lon - 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))),
                                    @lat - 10 / 111.1
                                  ) 
                            ),
                    mypoint
                    )
```

In the comments sections, Quassnoi notes `mypoint` is the field in the table which stores the coordinates. My question is, when dealing with longitude and latitude, what is `mypoint`? What exactly do we need to pass to `MBRContains` as the second argument?

My apologies if this is a trivial question. I wanted to ask Quassnoi directly, but I don't have enough reputation points to comment on the post. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried reading the MySQL documentation on [Spatial Analysis Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-analysis-functions.html)?

Comment: I have not. It looks like a good read, though. Thanks!