# how to use laravel to calculate the distance between 2 points

Tags: laravel

I have designed the way of getting the latitudes and longitudes of a location. but how can I get the distance between that location and another location. I am using LARAVEL. thanks a lot.

Comment: Where's the problem? How is this related to Lavarel? Are both locations stored in a database and you want to receive the distance directly from the database?

Comment: Actually yes, both locations are stored in the database and I want to get the distance directly from the database.

Comment: Then you probably need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Laravel problem, it's a PHP problem.  You have several options.

**1. Use Google's Maps API:**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/

*This is more designed for direction information however.*

**2. Use GeoDistance:**

https://github.com/0x13a/geodistance-php

*This will give you "straight line" distance if that is what you are looking* for.  The above link provides details on how to install using Composer. From there you will have to add the package to your app/config.php under service providers and I would also recommend creating an alias for it in the same file.