# Function rad2deg does not exist

Tags: php, mysqli

In my script I try to filter the selected data by its distance to the user. To achieve that I use this query which shall return every post in the radius of 10 kilometers:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ((rad2deg(acos((sin(deg2rad($actlat))*sin(deg2rad(lat))) + (cos(deg2rad($actlat))*cos(deg2rad(lat))*cos(deg2rad($actlon-lon))))))*111.13384) < 10";
```

The problem I‘m facing now is that I get this error returned:

```
Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: FUNCTION database_name.rad2deg does not exist
```

So I tried it another way where the function works as it should:

```
$test = rad2deg(x);
echo $test;
```

Why can‘t I use the `rad2deg` function in my query?

Comment: rad2deg is a php function not a mysql one.

Comment: Perform your calculations in PHP and assign the result to a variable, then use that in your query.

Comment: Oh okay, that‘s helpful! But the variables `lat` and `lon` are other values from the respective entry. How can I access them from outside the query like that?

Comment: MySQL has native support for all the functions you need here, you'll mostly just need to change the names and you can run this purely in SQL. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points might also be useful, if you can make use of the native spatial types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **degrees()** mysql function that converts radian values to degrees and the **radians()** function to convert from degrees to radians:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ((degrees(acos((sin(radians($actlat))*sin(radians(lat))) + (cos(radians($actlat))*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians($actlon-lon))))))*111.13384) < 10";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that‘s what I was looking for!