# MYSQL Count slowing down query considerably

Tags: mysql, count

I have a mysql query which returns rows within a given distance as below.  The query runs in around 0.002 seconds which is fine :

```
SELECT round( sqrt( ( ( (adverts.latitude - '53.757729') * (adverts.latitude - '53.757729') ) * 69.1 * 69.1 ) + ( (adverts.longitude - '-2.70344') * (adverts.longitude - '-2.70344') * 53 * 53 ) ), 1 ) as distance 
  FROM adverts 
  WHERE (adverts.status = 1) 
  AND (adverts.approved = 1) 
  AND (adverts.type_id = 3) 
  AND (adverts.latitude BETWEEN 53.049320633786 AND 54.466137366214) 
  AND (adverts.longitude BETWEEN -3.9017500913496 AND -1.5051299086504) 
  having (distance <= 49)
```

When I try to return the count of the rows using the query below, the execution time increases dramatically to 0.024 seconds.  Is there a faster way to get a count of the number of results.

```
SELECT count(*) from (SELECT round( sqrt( ( ( (adverts.latitude - '53.757729') * (adverts.latitude - '53.757729') ) * 69.1 * 69.1 ) + ( (adverts.longitude - '-2.70344') * (adverts.longitude - '-2.70344') * 53 * 53 ) ), 1 ) as distance 
  FROM adverts 
  WHERE (adverts.status = 1) 
  AND (adverts.approved = 1) 
  AND (adverts.type_id = 3) 
  AND (adverts.latitude BETWEEN 53.049320633786 AND 54.466137366214) 
  AND (adverts.longitude BETWEEN -3.9017500913496 AND -1.5051299086504) 
  having (distance <= 49)) as x;
```

Here is the explain on the secondquery which includes the count

```
1  PRIMARY  <derived2>  ALL   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  10352  
2  DERIVED  adverts     range r...  b..   11    NULL  10352  Using where; Using index
```

Comment: 0.024 seconds is hardly worth complaining about

Comment: @e4c5 this is not an argument. add more data to a table, and you will get a satisfying number. Do more requests - whatever. the question is clear and fair.

Comment: in that case @YourCommonSense this is premature optimizations because the indexes used (or not used) when there is a large amount of data in the tables can and will be different from the indexes used (or not used) now

Comment: @e4c5 the case has nothing to do with indexes

Comment: @YourCommonSense that is also a good point because the primary bottleneck may well be the count on a derived table

Comment: Hi @e4c5, thanks for your response regarding the 0.024 seconds.  I know its not that high, but our site has over 6000 concurrent users on at busy periods and this mysql query is run on one of the most popular web pages.  So if I could reduce the query time to 0.002 or similar then this would be a great performance boost.

Comment: have you looked at mysql spatial extensions? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38771805/267540 http://stackoverflow.com/a/38548557/267540

Comment: @e4c5 this is again irrelevant. the question is how to avoid a temporary table, not how to calculate a distance.

Comment: @Mark it would be a good start if you add EXPLAIN result for both queries. I am sure there is a temporary table involved, but it's better not to guess

Comment: @YourCommonSense on the contrary, the calculation could very well be another bottleneck. But you are also guessing.

Comment: My guess is that `WHERE round( sqrt...etc.` will be fractionally faster

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problem is coming from the temporary table to which the result of the first query is stored, I would suggest to change the query to avoid a nested select:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM adverts 
  WHERE (adverts.status = 1) 
  AND (adverts.approved = 1) 
  AND (adverts.type_id = 3) 
  AND (adverts.latitude BETWEEN 53.049320633786 AND 54.466137366214) 
  AND (adverts.longitude BETWEEN -3.9017500913496 AND -1.5051299086504) 
  AND (round( sqrt( ( ( (adverts.latitude - '53.757729') * (adverts.latitude - '53.757729') ) * 69.1 * 69.1 ) + ( (adverts.longitude - '-2.70344') * (adverts.longitude - '-2.70344') * 53 * 53 ) ), 1 ) <= 49);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try.  would it be quicker if I removed the two lines for the bounding box?

Comment: Well it may and it may not. You see, it's hardest job in the world, *profiling by email*. I know nothing of your database, data, environment - how can I tell?    Nevertheless, I don't think that any tweaks for the original query are on topic here. Are you still concerned of the second query performance?