# How do I calculate the Azimuth (angle to north) between two WGS84 coordinates in a single T-SQL query?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, geospatial, azimuth

[I found the solution for this question in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642555/how-do-i-calculate-the-azimuth-angle-to-north-between-two-wgs84-coordinates/1050914#1050914), but I can't translate it to a single query T-SQL, since my C# implementation requires branching (if then else).

I also found the following C# solution, which could be translated to a single query T-SQL but it doesn't produce the correct results

```
public static double GetAzimuth(WGSCoord c1, WGSCoord c2) { 
     var lat1 = DegToRad(c1.Latitude); 
     var lon1 = DegToRad(c1.Longitude); 
     var lat2 = DegToRad(c2.Latitude); 
     var lon2 = DegToRad(c2.Longitude);

     return RadToDeg(Math.Asin(Math.Sin(lon1 – lon2) * Math.Cos(lat2) / Math.Sin(Math.Acos(Math.Sin(lat2) * Math.Sin(lat1) + Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Cos(lon2 – lon1))))); 
}
```

Code from [Tamir Khason – Just code](http://khason.net/blog/wgs-to-utm-utm-to-wgs-conversions-geo-distance-azimuth-and-other-geographical-calculations-in-c/)

Could someone correct the code above or provide an alternate solution?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a query?

Comment: @quant_dev because I need performance. querying the results, processing and writing it back from C# is too slow

Comment: Do you batch the query, or query for one row at a time? (No offence, but I've seen this done...)

Comment: I get all results, process them and insert all at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace ifs with CASE expressions:

```
   if (latitudinalDifference == 0)
            {
                if (longitudinalDifference != 0)
                {
                    azimuth = Math.PI / 2d;
                }
            }
```

replace with:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @latitudinalDifference = 0 AND @longitudinalDifference <> 0 THEN ...
 ELSE ... END AS azimuth
```

replace consecutive ifs with nested selects:

```
if(some condition)
{
  i=1; 
}
else
{
 i=2;
}
if(some other condition)
{
  i++; 
}
```

replace with

```
SELECT i + CASE WHEN (some other condition) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM(
SELECT CASE WHEN (some condition) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS i
) AS t
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered creating an [assembly](http://tools.devshed.com/c/a/Web-Development/C-Assemblies/) with a SP in C# for sql server? Thats the route I'd probably go.

Comment: would you have a link to a better tutorial?

Comment: sure do. http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/clr-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a lot of the necessary spherical trigonometry in the answer to [SO 389211](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389211/geospatial-coordinates-and-distance-in-kilometers-updated-again/).  Copying and modifying what I wrote there:

Consider a sperical triangle with angles *A*, *B*, *C* at the vertices and sides *a*, *b*, *c* opposite those vertices (that is, side *a* is from *B* to *C*, etc.).
Applying this to the problem, we can call the two points given *B* and *C*, and we create a right spherical triangle with a right angle at *A*.

Consider this diagram:

```
                  + C
                 /|
                / |
            a  /  | b
           |  /   |
           |X/    |
           |/     |
         B +------+ A
              c
```

You are given two points *B* and *C*, and you want to determine the angle *X* = 90º - B.  The side *c* is equal to the difference in longitude, Δλ; the side *b* is equal to the difference in latitude, Δφ; the angle *A* is 90º, so sin *A* = 1 and cos *A* = 0.  To determine X, we want the value of *B* given *b*, *c* and *A*.

Looking at the problem from first principles, we need the two main spherical trigonometry equations:

1. The Sine Formula:

   ```
   sin A   sin B   sin C
   ----- = ----- = -----
   sin a   sin b   sin c
   ```
2. The Cosine Formula:

   ```
   cos a = cos b . cos c + sin b . sin c . cos A
   ```

Therefore, I believe an equation for *a* is:

```
cos a = cos Δλ . cos Δφ + sin Δλ . sin Δφ . cos 90º

a = arccos (cos Δλ . cos Δφ)
```

Given *a*, *b* and *A*, we can use the Sine Formula to determine *B*:

```
sin a   sin b
----- = ----
sin A   sin B
```

Or

```
        sin b . sin A
sin B = -------------
            sin a
```

Or, since A = 90º, sin A = 1, and sin B = sin (90º - X) = cos X:

```
        sin b
cos X = -----
        sin a
```

I rather suspect that if I bent my mind to it (or you bent your mind to it), you could come up with an answer that didn't involve using arccos followed by sin.

Answer (score 1):

In T-SQL, you could use the CASE expression

e.g.

```
SELECT ...
CASE 
    WHEN latD = 0 AND longD < 0 THEN ....
    WHEN latD < 0 AND longD = 0 THEN ....
```

etc.