# Find heading from current location to another location

Tags: core-location

I can find distance to another location by calling `[CLLocation distanceFromLocation:]`. Is there a corresponding way to find the heading from one location to another? Or do I have to write the trig myself?

Comment: This has been asked many times, here is one answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/6745131/1693173

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Notice that I'm not asking how to compute bearings. I'm asking if iOS has a built-in function that computes them, or if I have to implement the computation myself. I'd feel pretty silly defining a function that duplicates what already exists in the standard library.

Comment: There is no function to do that in the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the answer is "no."