# Return Value from geo.distance function in a select query

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I was playing around with the select for querying the index. I wanted to return a distance for a GeographyPoint I have in the index. I was trying something like this:
where GeoPoint is the location field

> $select=ID,geo.distance(GeoPoint, geography'POINT(-122.131577 47.678581)')

Is there a way to return distance in a Select statement if you have the lat and long and the location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search does not currently support returning the result of `geo.distance` in the search response. Please vote for the feature [on User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/17760211-support-geo-distance-in-select-result) to help us prioritize.

As a workaround, you can calculate the distance yourself. [This forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/cd9906ff-617e-4699-8047-96b090493cb3/returning-distance-from-search?forum=azuresearch) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010466/how-can-i-determine-the-distance-between-two-sets-of-lattitude-longitude-coordin) describe a few ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Even I wished it would work

But you cannot directly get the distance by using 'select'. It is currently enabled only as a filter and orderby property.

'SELECT' can be used only on the field names