# Xamarin.Forms: how to get driving distance between two points?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, geolocation, google-geolocation

My app currently uses Location Services. During debugging, I retrieve my current location using `GetLastKnownLocationAsync`: `myposition.Latitude` is *40.758896* while `myposition.Latitude` is *-73.985130*.

My SQL Database has a list of Walmart stores, and there's a Walmart with *Latitude* & *Longitude* of *40.660992* & *-73.7267629*.

How can I calculate the driving distance between my set of coordinates and Walmart's coordinates? It would be something like Google Maps' Driving Directions or Waze.

I understand that I can use this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010466/how-can-i-determine-the-distance-between-two-sets-of-latitude-longitude-coordina) to calculate the distance between two sets of point, but I assume apps like Google Maps or Waze consider the actual driving distance between two sets of points. The link above would be great if there were a straight street between two points. Obviously, that's not the case.

Comment: you need to find a GPS service that will provide this data for you.  Like https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start

Comment: Example service would be https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/distance-matrix

Answer (score 0):

I have used Xamarin.Essential library to find the distance between two point

You can use something like this

```
  var location = new Location(21.705723, 72.998199);
  var otherLocation = new Location(22.3142, 73.1752);
  double distance =  location.CalculateDistance(otherLocation,DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
```

Comment: will this return the driving distance? I mean to say will it give distance of by roads or by water (if points in sea or river) ?