# Calculate the direction of an object with geographical coordinates (latitude, longitude)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, math, geolocation, flash-builder

I have the coordinates of a player and another object. Both are with geographical coordinates (Latitude and longitude). I have also the direction in what the player is facing (compass). How can I calculate the angle to the other object from the player direction? e.g. I want to know if the object is to the right/left of the player and how many degrees.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378281/lat-lon-distance-heading-lat-lon

Comment: Possible dup of [#27928](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) though does care about _bearing_ as well as _distance_.

Comment: @mctylr: no dup I think, the formulas needed for bearing usually need the distance as one input parameter, so it's only one step in a more complicated calculation IME

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a few *it depends,* the answer is in essence, you want to know about how to do [geographic navigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance). One of the reasons *it depends* is that  the distances involve as well as the accuracy needed may influence the answer.

For short distances (<10km) you may be able to ignore the curvature of the Earth, and treat it like a two dimensional Cartesian map (latitude / longitude as X-Y). Then you question becomes basic trigonometry.

For larger distances, or improved accuracy, you can either approximate using an [spheroid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spheroid.html) model of the Earth (*assume the Earth is a perfect sphere*, which it is not) and calculate the [Great Circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_navigation) `bearing` and `distance`.

Or you can model the Earth as an [ellipsoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipsoid.html), and calculate its [geographic navigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance#Ellipsoidal-surface_formulae).

Two web pages that may help: [Details for computing distance using lat/long coordinates](http://www.johndcook.com/lat_long_details.html) and [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Note: [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) and [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) are often useful implementation details.

Small added note: `bearing` is a synonym for `heading` or `direction` in this context.

Answer (score 2):

You need this spherical trig formula: http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Crs Once you have the course (angle relative to true north), you can subtract off the compass heading of the direction the player is facing to get the relative heading.

(I don't know if Android automatically compensates for magnetic variation or not, but if not you'll have to account for it too to get the angle right in all areas)

Comment: Thank you for the formula and the explanation, was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

There are tools in the API to do this for you: [Location.bearingTo(Location)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29) and [GeomagneticSensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/GeomagneticField.html) will give you the direction from your position to the target - which you can then adjust based off the devices current heading.

If you've already got a MapView running & are lazy, set up a [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html), enableCompass and skip the GeomagneticSensor and let the MapView do it for you.

Comment: i'm not sure these are available if using flash-builder/actionscript. looking at the tags I believe the question is how to do it in flash-builder using android only as a target-platform for flex mobile.

Comment: If it's open source, try rewriting it

Comment: Thank you, but with flash builder that uses actionscript this function doesn´t exist :(