# How do I calculate the nearest country on a given heading?

Tags: ios, mapkit, geospatial, core-location, geography

I'd like to calculate the closest country (as viewed on a world map) in a given direction (provided in degrees) from a user's current location.

I realize one way of doing this is to use the formula provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378281/lat-lon-distance-heading-lat-lon) to step in, for example, 5-mile increments from point to point until I finally reach a country that is not the user's starting country. However, that seems horribly inefficient with regard to use of geocoding resources.

Do any of you know of a better algorithm I could use for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to reduce the amount of reverse geocoding operations is to treat this problem as a search for the border.  If you use a [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search), and reverse geocode each point, you find where the country changes from your current country to the adjacent country with a minimum number of reverse geocode operations.

In the binary search, your heading is constant, and you have a minimum range (5 miles) and a maximum range (12,000 miles), you are searching for the range at which the border lies.  Then you reverse geocode a position just beyond the border to find out what country is there.  One problem is that just beyond the border might be ocean.

Comment: Good point; thanks! I'd completely forgotten about binary search.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `MKReverseGeocoding`. Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382900/how-to-retrieve-users-current-city-name) for code examples.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question -- I realize I could use MKReverseGeocoding, but what I'm really trying to do is cut down on the amount of geocoding my app has to do -- [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW49) recommends only sending at most one geocoding request for every user action.